# How do i manipulate data at the loading time in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-components

In this section ,i am trying get all the subjects category headers dynamically as an 'li' tags.After that i am trying get all the subjects related to each category which results all the subjects getting loaded . But my requirement is when the page loads it should load only the first subject categories subjects not all.But all subjects category need to be loaded  as 'li' tags.attached the image for your reference. 
    [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zGiH.png)

home.component.ts

```
{
     ngOnInit() {

        this._httpService.SubjectPackagesAggregateDetails().map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
          (success) => {

            if (success.webServiceRequestStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
              this.subjectsAggregateDetailsPack = success.response;
            }
            else {
              this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'Error in getting subjects Aggregate Details', type: NotificationType.Error });
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'Not able to get Aggregate Details.', type: NotificationType.Error });
          });

        var GlobalVarAll = this;
        GlobalVarAll.imageShown = true;
        this._httpService.PopularCategoriesSubjects().map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
          (success) => {
            GlobalVarAll.imageShown = false;
            if (success.webServiceRequestStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
              GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJson = [];
              GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJsonCatTitle = [];
              GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJsonCatAssmntsDelivered = [];
              var allCategoryDataArray = success.response.CategoryData;
              var i=0;
              for (let CategorySubjectsArr of allCategoryDataArray) {
                let catTitle = i++; // as we are unable to add string i.e. category_title so using integer.
                if(typeof GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJson[catTitle] == 'undefined'){
                    GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJson[catTitle] = [];
                    GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJsonCatTitle[catTitle] = CategorySubjectsArr.CategoryTitle;
                    GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJsonCatAssmntsDelivered[catTitle] = CategorySubjectsArr.CategoryAssessmentsDelivered;
                }
                  for (let allSubjectArr of CategorySubjectsArr.CategorySubjects) {
                    for (let allSubjectVariantDetails of allSubjectArr.SubjectVariants) {
                      GlobalVarAll.allSubjectsJson[catTitle].push({ 
                        "CategoryTitle": CategorySubjectsArr.CategoryTitle, 
                        "VariantId": allSubjectVariantDetails.VariantId, 
                        "DifficultyLevel": allSubjectVariantDetails.DifficultyLevel, 
                        "Duration": allSubjectVariantDetails.Duration, 
                        "SubjectId": allSubjectArr.SubjectId, 
                        "SubjectTitle": allSubjectArr.SubjectTitle, 
                        "SubjectImagePath": allSubjectArr.SubjectImagePath, 
                        "SubjectEntryLevel": allSubjectArr.SubjectEntryLevel, 
                        "SubjectPurchasedMembersCount": allSubjectVariantDetails.PurchasedByMembers 
                      });                  
                    }                
                  }  

              }
            }
            else {
              this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'Error in getting all subjects', type: NotificationType.Error });
            }
          },
          (error) => {
            this.notificationBarService.create({ message: 'Not able to get all Subjects.', type: NotificationType.Error });
          });

      }

}
```

Comment: categories are displayed like tabs(if you click on IT it will display all content for that category)?

Comment: but right now,it's loading all the contents when the page loads.but i want it load the first tabs value only when the page loads

Comment: I can't really understand your response data but can't you filter the response by a category?If yes you need to move the request in a separate function then call it in `ngOnInit()` like `getData(categoryName)`. And like this you call it for every category with a `click` event